# NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue send nothing

Tags: codenameone

I use  NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue or addToQueueAndWait to send requests on my server.

It works on Android but I have an issue on my iPhone.

I ask my user to login but when I create the request and call addToQueue (addToQueueAndWait has the same effect) no request has sent.

Strangely, if I restart the app, the login is stored locally and the app tries to sync ... and it works ! The request has sent and I receveid the server's answer.

On Android it always work.

What am I doing wrong ? I tried to run the NetworkManager on a thread, same issue :/

Comment: Normally this should act the same so I'll need more details of what exactly you are doing. It's possible that a different request is stuck in the queue and taking time to "time out" on iOS but that's just a guess. I suggest adding logging and looking through that.  You can also increase the network thread count to see if this is related to a request stuck in the queue. You can look at the network monitor in the simulator to get a sense of what "should happen" and then guess what might be failing on iOS based on that view.

Comment: I have added " NetworkManager.getInstance().updateThreadCount(2);" before addToQueue and it works !

Answer (score 0):

If I had to throw a wild guess based on the question I'd say you are connecting to HTTP instead of an HTTPS server and that's failing for some reason see this: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/ios-http-urls.html

Comment: It was my first thought too, but It works on other request.

Comment: Based on your other comment it seems you have a request stuck in the queue that doesn't complete or timeout on iOS. I suggest logging so you can see what's going on there.